# Skewness and log transformation and meta analysis

Tags: normal-distribution, skewness, lognormal-distribution, histogram

I am using 3 papers for a mini meta analysis  using data (mean and SD) of both the experimental and control groups.
Using the means I have made 2 histograms displaying distribution. Only one of them has a right skewness (tails off to the right). Do I have to log transform both data sets or only the one that is skewed? Would log10 transformation be better to use than log2?

Comment: If you transform only one, they're no longer comparable. If you transform everything, the parameters don't mean what they did. e.g. if you're interested in comparing means of original variables, you have to be very careful about how to do that (if that was the aim, I would avoid taking logs, personally, outside some special cases)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: However, avoiding taking logs does not necessarily mean "just ignore the skewness in the variable".